# ILogger _logger.Debug("Something") - Any way for the compiler to remove it?

Tags: c#, performance, logging, windows-phone-7

I got a pretty common scenario, namely a self implemented ILogger interface. It contains several methods like **_logger.Debug("Some stuff")** and so on. The implementation is provided by a LoggingService, and used in classes the normal way.

Now I have a question regarding performance, I am writing for Windows Phone 7, and because of the limited power of these devices, little things may matter.

I do not want to:

- Include a precompiler directive on each line, like #IF DEBUG
- Use a condition like log4net e.g. _logger.DebugEnabled

The way I see it, in the release version, I just return NullLoggers, which contain an empty implementation of the interface, doing nothing.

The question is: Does the compiler recognize such things (may be hard, he can't know on compile time which logger I assign). Is there any way to give .NET a hint for that?

The reason for my question, I know entering an empty function will not cause a big delay, no problem there. But there are a lot of strings in the source code of my application, and if they are never used, they do not really need to be part of my application...

Or am I overthinking a tiny problem (perhaps the "string - code" ratio just looks awful in my code editor, and its no big deal anyway)..

Thanks for tips,
Chris

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [Conditional attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute.aspx):

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
public void Debug(string message) { /* ... */ }
```

The compiler will remove all calls to this method for any build configurations that don't match the string in the conditional attribute.  Note that this attribute is applied to the *method* not the call site.  Also note that it is the *call site instruction* that is removed, not the method itself.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably a very small concern to have logging code in your application that does not "run". The overhead of the "null" logger or conditionals is likely to be very small in the scheme of things. The strings will incur memory overhead which could be worrying for a constrained device, but as it is WP7 the minimum specs are not that constrained in reality.

I understand that logging code looks fugly though. :)

If you really want to strip that logging code out...

In .Net you can use the [ConditionalAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute.aspx) to mark methods for conditional compilation. You could leverage this feature to ensure that all logging calls are removed from compilation for specified build configurations. As long as methods that you have decorated with the conditional attributes follows a few rules, the compiler will literally strip the call chain out.

However, if you wanted to use this approach then you would have to forgo your interface design as the conditional attribute cannot be applied to interface members, and you cannot implement interfaces with conditional members.

Comment: Thanks, I may try the approach and switch to subclassing instead of interfaces for the logger (there are only two anyway). But I agree, priority is very low, lets first get the app running without errors :-)